# How to capture results when datestamp has special exception

Tags: sql-server

I'm fairly certain I can use a CASE statement in this instance, but I'm clearly not looking at this right.

In my WHERE clause, when a datestamp resides in the month of July, I need to <strike>group</strike> lump it into my results for the month of August. Here's what I'm trying, but 
I'm missing the mark:

```
and CPTrn_DateTime = case
        when datepart(month, CPTrn_DateTime) = 7 then datepart(month, CPTrn_DateTime) in (7,8)
```

The reason I was trying to use a CASE statement is because *only* for the month of July do I need those results to be associated with August results. The reason I can't do a simple date range is because I need the logic to work for all dates moving forward as time goes on.

Here's the entire query:

```
DECLARE @month INT

SET @month = 8

SELECT DISTINCT cp.CPTrn_Key
    ,ch.Chg_Ref_No
    ,c.Cust_Alias
    ,ch.Chg_Total_Units
    ,ch.Chg_Amount
    ,cp.CPTrn_DateTime
FROM PDICompany_2049_01..CP_Transactions cp(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN PDICompany_2049_01..Customers c(NOLOCK) ON CPTrn_Cust_Key = Cust_Key
INNER JOIN PDICompany_2049_01..Products p(NOLOCK) ON cp.CPTrn_Prod_Key = Prod_Key
LEFT JOIN PDICompany_2049_01..CP_Billing_Details CPBD(NOLOCK) ON CPBd.CPBillDtl_CPTrn_Key = cp.CPTrn_Key
    AND CPTrn_Cust_Key = CPBD.CPBillDtl_Cust_Key
    AND CPBD.CPBillDtl_Rec_Type = 1
LEFT JOIN PDICompany_2049_01..Customer_Locations cl(NOLOCK) ON c.Cust_WhPrcNtc_Def_CustLoc_Key = cl.CustLoc_Key
    AND ((CustLoc_Type & 2) <> 0)
LEFT JOIN Charges ch ON ch.Chg_Ref_No = cpbd.CPBillDtl_Invoice_No
WHERE cp.CPTrn_Tran_Type != 0
    AND c.Cust_Alias = 'MONTGOMERY CRANES, LLC'
    AND CPBillDtl_Invoice_No IS NOT NULL
    AND CPTrn_DateTime = CASE 
        WHEN datepart(month, CPTrn_DateTime) = 7
            THEN datepart(month, CPTrn_DateTime) IN (7,8)
        ELSE datepart(month, CPTrn_DateTime) = @month
        END AS 'CPTrn_DateTime'
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: what is the error you are receiving, the rest of the statement, sample data, etc.

Comment: We need the rest of the query.  It seems like you must be grouping by something.  You could `group by case when month(CPTrn_DateTime) = 7 then 8 else month(CPTrn_DateTime) end`

Comment: Or if it's not group by then maybe you can just use `and month(CPTrn_Datetime) in (7,8)`.

Comment: So you want *all* years when you put in `8` for `@month`? So, if `@month` has a value of 8, you want ***all*** rows for the dates `2010-07-01` to `2010-08-31`, `2011-07-01` to `2011-08-31`, `2012-07-01` to `2012-08-31`, ... `2019-07-01` to `2019-08-31`?

Comment: No, it would be just for 2019, but that's a simple addendum. Understandable you would want to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this is a `CASE` **expression** (`Case` statements don't exist in T-SQL) with the `DATEPART` function is going to likely ruin performance.

You don't "group" in a `WHERE`, you do that in your `GROUP By`, so i'm reading through the lines, but what's wrong with "normal" date logic?

```
WHERE CPTrn_DateTime >= '20190701'
  AND CPTrn_DateTime < '20190901'
```

Edit: Simple date logic is still what you are after:

```
DECLARE @Month int = 8,
        @Year int = 2019;

DECLARE @DateStart date = DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, IIF(@Month = 8, 7, @MOnth),1);
DECLARE @DateEnd date = DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @Month+1, 1);

SELECT ...
FROM...
WHERE CPTrn_DateTime >= @DateStart
      AND CPTrn_DateTime < @DateEnd
```

Comment: Simple data logic is still what you need, @jw11432 :)

Comment: No wonder I couldn't get it to work, I've never even heard of that DATEFROMPARTS function before. Thank you! EDIT: I had to declare the DateStart/End as DATE data types, but otherwise this worked great, thank you again!

Comment: That was my bad, sorry @jw11432 !

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it all in the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cp.CPTrn_Key
    ,ch.Chg_Ref_No
    ,c.Cust_Alias
    ,ch.Chg_Total_Units
    ,ch.Chg_Amount
    ,cp.CPTrn_DateTime
FROM PDICompany_2049_01..CP_Transactions cp(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN PDICompany_2049_01..Customers c(NOLOCK) ON CPTrn_Cust_Key = Cust_Key
INNER JOIN PDICompany_2049_01..Products p(NOLOCK) ON cp.CPTrn_Prod_Key = Prod_Key
LEFT JOIN PDICompany_2049_01..CP_Billing_Details CPBD(NOLOCK) ON CPBd.CPBillDtl_CPTrn_Key = cp.CPTrn_Key
    AND CPTrn_Cust_Key = CPBD.CPBillDtl_Cust_Key
    AND CPBD.CPBillDtl_Rec_Type = 1
LEFT JOIN PDICompany_2049_01..Customer_Locations cl(NOLOCK) ON c.Cust_WhPrcNtc_Def_CustLoc_Key = cl.CustLoc_Key
    AND ((CustLoc_Type & 2) <> 0)
LEFT JOIN Charges ch ON ch.Chg_Ref_No = cpbd.CPBillDtl_Invoice_No
WHERE cp.CPTrn_Tran_Type != 0
    AND c.Cust_Alias = 'MONTGOMERY CRANES, LLC'
    AND CPBillDtl_Invoice_No IS NOT NULL
    AND @month = case when month(CPTrn_DateTime) = 7 then 8 else month(CPTrn_DateTime) end
```

I believe `order by 1` is superfluous.